# C# reportviewer control - DynamicTable example

Tags: c#, winforms, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I need to create report with a table in which the columns can be dynamically selected so that they can be hidden by user input in a windows form.

I've found an example which is almost exactly what I need but I want to be able to add extra details to the report such as a company logo, address, title etc. I can't figure out how to do this in the structure of the example.

c# example on this site
http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

the example:
http://www.gotreportviewer.com/DynamicTable.zip

Adam

Comment: What did you tried? Did you had a look at the SalesOrder demo?

Comment: I'm using the RRSNewReader demo, trying to use parameters to hide the columns now

Comment: OK I can hide a column with parameters with this in hidden field =not(Parameters!myparam.Value) but this leaves a huge gap where the coluun was, so I need to find a way of changing the column width

Comment: Sascha what title/page is the SalesOrder demo under?

Comment: I've seen it on the screenshot page. It has a logo on it, so it should show you how to da that. I don't know the download location.

Comment: resolved by setting the Column visibility properties instead of field properties

Comment: If you found your answer, post it as the answer, so others can benefit.